# Get data from localstorage and display it in view using ngx-translate | Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, local-storage, ngx-translate

I have a task have to display data from localstorage in html using ngx-translate. I have an backend spring-boot application with a controller that sends data downloaded from the database to the frontend.
This data is stored in localstorage. They are literals. I have little in common with Angular.. I work in Java, but I need to do it :/ I am asking for your understanding.

```
localstorage:

          key            |          value
--------------------------------------------------
Platform.Title           |         "Title"
Platform.Home            |         "Home"
Platform.Dashboard       |         "Dashboard"
Library.Title            |         "Library"
Library.Home             |         "Home"
Library.Dashboard        |         "Dashboard"
```

This what i need to do is: make service to get data from localstorage, i know i have to do it with

```
localstorage.get(key);
```

What I need to achieve is e.q

```
<mat-card-title>{{'Platform.Title' | translate }}</mat-card-title>
```

and this should show value of "Platform.Title" - here "Title"

I have keys which starts with different values Platform or Library. In platform.component.html i need to display all starts with "Platform" and in library.component.html all with "Library"

My ideas so far have not worked, it does not even show because it is a shame. I have no idea how should servis in Angular looks like or some ngx-translate loader to achieve the planned effect.
Could someone please help me? Show the way to a solution or maybe a sample solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your data from local storage in this way

in your component.ts

```
public title;

ngOnInit(){
  this.title = localStorage.getItem('KEY');
}
```

in your HTML

```
<mat-card-title>{{title | translate }}</mat-card-title>
```

Comment: It's not working with " | translate ". Just {{title}} works and gave response in quotes. What could be the reason why "translate" is not working. I have ngx-translate dependency.

Comment: It is some method to read all literals start with e.q "Platform" and using saving all using loop ?

Comment: do you use this part in your module

TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [Http] // Here comes HttpClient instead Http
  }
})

Comment: you can get all key using for loop

  // Iterate over localStorage and insert the keys of unsaved image datas
        for (let k = 0; k < localStorage.length; k++) {
            if (localStorage.key(k).startsWith('Platform') && localStorage.key(k).length > 'Platform'.length) {
                arr.push(localStorage.key(k));
            }
        }

Comment: It should be in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

**in your app module add**

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);}
```

**in your app component add**

```
 constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
}
```